# Is there a smarter way to achive replacement with variables in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm a beginner with Javascript and I have following Question:

I have to replace the patterns #XY1, #XY2, #XY3 or #XY4 with the SAME replacement in a string.

Eg. replacement with AA:

this is #XY1 an #XY3 example #XY1 --> this is AA an AA example AA

The patterns occur randomly and it is possible to have several (different) once in the string. How do I replace them without iterating too often through the string? So i DO NOT look for suggestions like:

```
str = str.replace(/:#XY1:/g, "Replacement")
str = str.replace(/:#XY2:/g, "Replacement")
str = str.replace(/:#XY3:/g, "Replacement")
str = str.replace(/:#XY4:/g, "Replacement")
```

or something with a loop.

I hope to find a solution where I just have to iterate ONCE through the string and replace all patterns #XY PLUS the next variable character.

I can not use .replaceAll because of some version problems.

Thank you for your help and have a nice day! Cheers, Josh

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Is this always the four strings (starting with `XY`), followed by the numbers one to four?

Comment: Combine all regular expressions into one expression, e.g. `str = str.replace(/:#XY[1-4]:/g, "Replacement")`

Comment: The pattern to replace always starts with #XY, always followed by one number (1, 2, 3 or 4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use one regex and wildcard the digit.

```js
const repl = (source, value) => source.replace(/#XY\d/g, value);

console.log(repl('this is #XY1 an #XY3 example #XY1', 'AA')) // this is AA an AA example AA
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
/#XY\d/
```

[image]

```js
const str = "this is #XY1 an #XY3 example #XY1";
const replacement = "AA";

const result = str.replace(/#XY\d/g, replacement);
console.log(result);
```